# F# - Set Property if changed

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I have a class with properties that have several side effects that fire when its setters are called, such as change events fired and/or rendering actions. How could I design a function that would set the property only if its value needs to change?

With refs, I would just do something like this:

```
let setIfChanged (oldVal: Ref<'T>) (newVal: 'T) = if newVal <> !oldVal then oldVal := newVal 
let y = ref 0
setIfChanged y 1
```

However, mutable properties aren't refs, and I can't seem to find any way to design such a thing that will compile. For example,

```
let setIfChanged oldVal newVal = if newVal <> oldVal then oldVal <- newVal
```

will just tell me that oldVal is not mutable.

Is there a way to annotate oldVal so that it is for mutable (settable) properties? Or is there a better way?

Comment: well it's a shame (normally you'll want the setter to be as clever to not do side-effects when there has nothing changed) you cannot change the source - personally I would consider wrapping the *offending* types - Tomas answer seems a nice way to do this *shortish*

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is any easy nice way to do this "for free".

One trick that might make this a bit easier is that you can actually treat the getter and setter of the property as functions, so you can write `setIfChanged` as a function taking two functions:

```
let setIfChanged getter setter v = 
  if getter() <> v then setter(v)
```

Given a class `A` with proeperty `P`, you can then call this using `set_P` and `get_P` as parameters:

```
let a = A()
setIfChanged a.get_P a.set_P 0
setIfChanged a.get_P a.set_P 1
```

The fact that the compiler allows you to access `get_P` and `set_P` is a little known trick - so it might be a bit confusing for many people.
For completeness, here is the definition of `A` that I used for testing:

```
type A() =
  let mutable p = 0
  member x.P 
    with get() = p
    and set(v) = printfn "Setting!"; p <- v
```

A more sophisticated approach would be to use quotations and reflection, which would be slower, but it would let you write something like `setIfChanged <@ a.P @> 42`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
let setIfChanged (oldVal: 'a byref) (newVal : 'a) = if newVal <> oldVal then oldVal <- newVal
let mutable test = 42
setIfChanged &test 24
```

That being said, given your explanation of goals, I would recommend looking at [Gjallarhorn](https://github.com/ReedCopsey/Gjallarhorn).  It provides support for signaling on top of mutable values, and is designed to be extremely flexible in terms of what happens when a value changes.  It could be used as an underlying mechanism upon which you could easily build your signals when things change (if it doesn't already provide what you need via the `View` module).

---

Edit:

Given your comment that the property in question lies in a third party assembly, one option would be to use the dynamic support in F# to override the `op_DynamicAssignment` operator (`?<-`) to dynamically dispatch to the method, but raise your "notification" in the process.

Given:

```
let (?<-) source property (value : 'a) = 
    let p = source.GetType().GetProperty(property)
    let r = p.GetValue(source, null) :?> 'a
    if (r <> value) then
        printfn "Changing value"
        source.GetType().GetProperty(property).SetValue(source, value, null)
```

You can call `someObj?TheProperty <- newVal`, and you'll see the "Changing value" print only if the value has actually changed.

Internally, this works by using reflection to get the old value of the property and set the new one, so it's not going to have the best performance characteristics, but as you're using it to raise property changed type notifications, that's likely not a problem.

Comment: How would that work with an object property? eg `setIfChanged foo.Text "bar"`. Also, I don't have control over the classes and their members, which are defined in an external C# library.

Comment: @dannytoone Ahh, that'd have to work against a field.  It won't work against a property... didn't realize you don't have access to the types.

Comment: @dannytoone Gave you an alternative using the dynamic support in F# to "wrap" the access, allowing you to do your operation in the process.